# How to stretch the image vertically by using flex box properties without using height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to stretch the image vertically based on the content by using flex properties without using height. If the content size is increases or decreases image should be stretch automatically.
please, can anyone suggest me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance...
below is my code snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.section-inner {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.at-crop-box-content {
    background: #ffffff;
    flex-basis: 60%;
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.at-crop-box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.at-crop-box-thumb {
    flex-basis: 40%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
}
.at-crop-img {
      max-width: 100%;
}
.at-crop-head {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0.8;
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.at-crop-info {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="section-inner">
<div class="at-crop-box">
   <div class="at-crop-box-thumb">
       <figure><img class="at-crop-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/wCjFWjB/apple-2819015-340.jpg"></figure>
   </div>
    <div class="at-crop-box-content">
       <h2 class="at-crop-head">Heading is here</h2>
       <p class="at-crop-info">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to vertically align an image inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div)

Comment: How much should the image vertically stretch?Should it take up complete height ? In that case it would look abnormally stretched.

Comment: I want to stretch the image automatically how the content is stretch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is something you need?

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="section-inner">
<div class="at-crop-box">
         <div class="at-crop-box-thumb">
             <figure><img class="at-crop-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/wCjFWjB/apple-2819015-340.jpg"></figure>
         </div>
          <div class="at-crop-box-content">
             <h2 class="at-crop-head">Heading is here</h2>
             <p class="at-crop-info">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.section-inner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.at-crop-box-content {
  background: #ffffff;
  flex-basis: 60%;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.at-crop-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.at-crop-box-thumb {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figure {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 10px; */ /* Use margin and padding as you like */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
}
.at-crop-img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.at-crop-head {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.at-crop-info {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #000000;
}
```

A Working codepen: https://codepen.io/leo-melin/pen/xxbgNxK

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to fit the image vertically like this?

Then provide

```
.figure {
  display: flex;
}
```

Since you have already provided stretch for items, the content should be display flex to get it reflected.

```css
.figure {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.section-inner {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.at-crop-box-content {
    background: #ffffff;
    flex-basis: 60%;
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.at-crop-box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.at-crop-box-thumb {
    flex-basis: 40%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
}
.at-crop-img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
}
.at-crop-head {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0.8;
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.at-crop-info {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section-inner">
    <div class="at-crop-box">
          <div class="at-crop-box-thumb">
              <figure><img class="at-crop-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/wCjFWjB/apple-2819015-340.jpg"></figure>
          </div>
          <div class="at-crop-box-content">
              <h2 class="at-crop-head">Heading is here</h2>
              <p class="at-crop-info">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** You have 2 options:

```
.at-crop-box-thumb img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

or

```
.at-crop-box-thumb figure {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch; /* in this case without this it still works btw */
}
```

---

**Long answer version:**

> I want to stretch the image vertically based on the content

Add `height: 100%` to the `img`

> by using flex properties without using height

Why? `height: 100%` is super simple, it does exactly what you want

> If the content size is increases or decreases image should be stretch automatically.

`height: 100%` does exactly that

> can anyone suggest me in the right direction?

Use `height: 100%`. Here's the image as I inspect the DOM.
[image]
As you can see, the `figure` element content already fully vertical stretches with the `align something: stretch` you set. There's only the `img` element inside it is not stretched yet. You then have 2 options: simply set `img{ height: 100%; }`, or again make the `figure` a flex container, then `align-items: stretch;` to align its content (`img`), yet it's more complicated and doesn't make as semantical sense as `height: 100%`. I suggest using `height: 100%` despite you said you wanted a solution without using height.

Here's the code after add 1 line of code `height: 100%` in `img`. But it'll likely look terrible, because its width is relatively smaller than its height if the content on the right is too long, set an image's sizes based on dynamic text isn't a good idea. But as what you want is to stretch the image's height base on the content height, here's the code.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.section-inner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.at-crop-box-content {
  background: #ffffff;
  flex-basis: 60%;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.at-crop-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.at-crop-box-thumb {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.at-crop-box-thumb img {
  height: 100%;
}
.at-crop-img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.at-crop-head {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.at-crop-info {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section-inner">
    <div class="at-crop-box">
      <div class="at-crop-box-thumb">
        <figure><img class="at-crop-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/wCjFWjB/apple-2819015-340.jpg"></figure>
      </div>
      <div class="at-crop-box-content">
        <h2 class="at-crop-head">Heading is here</h2>
        <p class="at-crop-info">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content
          of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
          distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable
          English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the case you don't want to use `height: 100%`, here's the code using flex. Add

```
.at-crop-box-thumb figure {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.section-inner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.at-crop-box-content {
  background: #ffffff;
  flex-basis: 60%;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.at-crop-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.at-crop-box-thumb {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.at-crop-box-thumb figure {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.at-crop-img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.at-crop-head {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.at-crop-info {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section-inner">
    <div class="at-crop-box">
      <div class="at-crop-box-thumb">
        <figure><img class="at-crop-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/wCjFWjB/apple-2819015-340.jpg"></figure>
      </div>
      <div class="at-crop-box-content">
        <h2 class="at-crop-head">Heading is here</h2>
        <p class="at-crop-info">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content
          of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
          distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable
          English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give display block and give height 100%  to your image;

```
.at-crop-img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height:100%;
      display:block;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.section-inner {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.at-crop-box-content {
    background: #ffffff;
    flex-basis: 60%;
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.at-crop-box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.at-crop-box-thumb {
    flex-basis: 40%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
}
.at-crop-img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height:100%;
      display:block;
}
.at-crop-head {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0.8;
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.at-crop-info {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="section-inner">
<div class="at-crop-box">
   <div class="at-crop-box-thumb">
       <figure><img class="at-crop-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/wCjFWjB/apple-2819015-340.jpg"></figure>
   </div>
    <div class="at-crop-box-content">
       <h2 class="at-crop-head">Heading is here</h2>
       <p class="at-crop-info">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use height: 100%; I only want the flexbox property to stretch the image height.